# How to bring to front the Print page ( Winform)?

Tags: winforms, printing

I'm printing the screen of the winform page.

**I click print, then the  ["select printer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3LC8.png) page shows up,
i select the "save to pdf" and click Print.
The "Print to Pdf" window appears, but it stays on the back of the winform.**

**How can i bring to front this window ["Print to Pdf" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpCwn.png)?**

Ps : This is a simple GUI, and the print page is the systems default.

Comment: Is minimizing your WinForms form or sending it to back can help you?

Comment: I dont want the Winform minimised, but just to have the "Print to Pdf" pop out on the front of the Winform.

Comment: then this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822314/bring-another-application-to-front

Comment: It somehow helped on the fact that on click, i can call an external application, but still no luck. The print page is the system default which after selecting the printer, calls "splwow64.exe" which stays on background.

Comment: Can't you call the exe by yourself?

Comment: I did it, but no screen shows up. It seems that this is a sub process which is called after the select printer page.

Comment: You can try to change the `TopMost` property to `false` (this is the opposite to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526579)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is:

**From the Winform i deleted :**

**PrintPreviewDialog1 and PrintDocument1_Print**

**then reinserted them from the toolbox.**

Somehow, this solved the problem and brought the "print page" to the front.